# Apple "Avoid writing cache files to disk." - where should I save cache?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In [Apple's Performance Tuning Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html) there is a writing:

> Avoid writing cache files to disk. The only exception to this rule is
>   when your app quits and you need to write state information that can
>   be used to put your app back into the same state when it is next
>   launched.

I'm saving a lot of cache files in Library/Cache directory, because my app deals with web services, and nobody likes the white screen. What does this statement mean? I shouldn't do this or what?

Thank you!

Comment: What does caching have to do with "the white screen"?

Comment: I only read: if you are interested in performance, then don't write cache stuff to disk. Most likely that is because disk is slow. So keep the cache in memory, I'd say.

Comment: Another point is, what is the expire-time of the data. If you need the data, or still use the data after a appkill (eg cache of images of website, ... ) you can write it. If you want to cache runtime information, writing to a file make no sense since it's slow and not needed in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, "avoid" means "avoid if possible, because writing/reading is relatively slow". If by caching a small amount of  data (I assume the definitions of the web services retrieved from somewhere?) you can improve the performance of your app's *startup*, by all means do it. If you are only using this data for one run of your application, and the next run will re-fetch this anyway, use an in-memory cache.

`Library\Caches` is basically designed to store data you fetched from somewhere which provides performance boosts when stored locally.

The text from Apple feels like more a general guideline against *overusing* storage if you don't need data to persist from one run of your application to another.